# GSM vulnerabilities

Tags: security, remote-control, gsm

I heard that there are inherent flaws in the GSM protocol that make it possible for someone to impersonate a network operator and do all sorts of nasty things remotely, even if your phone is off.

Is this true? Is it also true of today's Android phones?

Comment: in the case of android upto `4.3(jelly Bean)` the OS is most vulnerable

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your carrier's technology. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM#GSM_service_security) all the encryption used in GSM (A5/1, A5/2 and A5/3) have been cracked (albeit some are more difficult to decrypt than others). [A5/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/2), the least secure of these, is no longer in any GSM-related standards (and newer phones shouldn't implement it). A5/3 has not been decrypted in 3G, but people have cracked it.

GPRS and EDGE (GSM's data protocols) - the "G" or "E" above your network signal status icon - *may* also be vulnerable. It depends on your carrier's encryption level. Some carriers don't encrypt GPRS data at all. Others will use the GEA/1 or GEA/2 - which both have a publicly available tool called "gprsdecode" available to crack them. GEA/3 is "relatively hard to break", but the recommendation is to upgrade to GEA/4, which uses 128-bit encryption. UMTS (aka 3G) is more secure, meaning that your data is safely encrypted.

To be certain that you're actually using *your carriers* network, your carrier needs to have implemented USIM, and your phone needs to support it - which is guaranteed if your carrier supports UMTS and your phone supports 3G. However, to get these  additional security features you need to use UMTS - which means your phone can't be on "prefer 2G networks" mode, and your phone can't connect to 2G networks.

Now, as for "doing nasty things while your phone is off" - I really don't think this is possible, but perhaps you can clarify what these "nasty things" are? And also perhaps where you've read about this.

**TL;DR** depends on your carrier and if you use 2G networks or 3G networks.

Comment: By "nasty things" I mean using the phone's microphone to listen to its surroundings (without being in a call). It's a rumor I heard recently, but from people I can't discount easily.

Comment: I can't say for sure (but it seems very unlikely to me that there would be microphone listening), but if you use a custom ROM/AOSP ROM such as [CyanogenMod](http://cyanogenmod.org) in which the code is open there's no way android itself could be doing any spying (low-level phone firmware is another matter, and it's pretty hard to know if it's doing anything because it's all closed-source.)